# Resistance change on the GST of a keyboard YPG235

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible to increase the resistance of the keys on YPG235 to make the keys a little heavier?

Answer (score 1):

No. Any keyboard will either have the keys be weighted or unweighted. It is a physical feature of the keyboard just like the number of keys a keyboard  has and it cannot be changed. It's a big thing to consider when getting a keyboard.